rsync command where I exclude all and include specific files
I have this in a Jenkinsfile:
args=(
    -avz
    --delete

    # Config Files
    --include="config/captcha_challenge.sql"
    --include="config/captcha_user.sql"
    
    # Libraries
    --include="lib/**"
    
    # Login Files
    --include="login/**"
    
    # App Files
    --include="index.php"
    
    # Other Files
    --include=".env"
    --include=".htaccess"
    
    # Images already on destination
    --exclude="background/"
    --exclude="objects/"
    --exclude="textures/"

    --exclude="*"

    /tmp/WebApp/
    /media/storage/WebApp/
)
rsync "${args[@]}"

But I can't get it to work.
Right now I have only:
background/
objects/
textures/

I've tried moving the exclude=* to the beginning but nothing changes.
I've only managed to get index.php .env and .htaccess

You can't include files inside config, lib, login, etc if those directories themselves are excluded. If you use --exclude="*" it 1) needs to be at the end so that the --include options override it, and 2) you need to --include every directory (and subdirectory) that you want it to include files from.
